# Kotlin Flow vs Channel for Concurrent Processing

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to build a simple multithreaded processing application that interacts with a messaging API. Currently, I have abstracted this API into a flow as follows:

```
    fun myAbstractedAPI(): Flow<Message> = callbackFlow<Message> {
    repeat(threadCount) {
        launch {
            while (true) {
                    val message = getMessageFromApiAsync.await()
                    trySendBlocking(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    awaitClose { channel.close() }
}
```

This concurrently polls my API and emits the Messages into a flow. All good so far...

I can then interact with this flow in my main function like this:

```
        myAbstractedAPI.collect {
       // do something with the Messages
    }
```

I can of course collect the flow and launch coroutines to process the flow, but I feel like this might be putting me in a bottleneck since the main thread needs to iterate the flow to assign work.

Perhaps channels are a better solution? For example, if `myAbstractedAPI()` produced a channel, then i could spin up N channel consuming threads that could run independent of the main thread.

Is it a valid concern to be worried about the "bottleneck" of having a single thread iterating the flow to assign work to worker threads. And if so - is a channel based approach better?

Answer (score 0):

> I can of course collect the flow and launch coroutines to process the flow, but I feel like this might be putting me in a bottleneck since the main thread needs to iterate the flow to assign work.

This reflects a fundamental misunderstanding of how coroutines work.

First: even if you were running only on Dispatchers.Main, you would not be blocking or taking up an entire thread.  Whenever there wasn't an element to process, the thread pool running the collect coroutine would do other things.  You would not be bottlenecked.

Second, you don't have to use the main thread, and you most likely won't be either unless you manually choose to do so.  Most likely, you'll be running on some thread pool, e.g. Dispatchers.Default, which does not include the main thread.

It is true that you will not -- in this design -- be able to process multiple elements from the flow concurrently.  If you wanted to do that, however, the appropriate approach would be to use flatMapMerge or some other API that processed flow elements concurrently, not to abandon flows.